# Android phone as a Live Linux USB stick?

Tags: linux, android

I got only a quick question before I actually try to do this thing myself. HTC phones with Android can be used as classical USB mass storage sticks, so I'm planning to use one as a live Linux USB stick (for gentoo minimal or something so). Question is, before I try to install grub on that and possibly break something, does anyone have such setup working, or are there any caveats I should know?

Thanks

-m

Comment: You'll probably have a better response on http://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2351/optimal-linux-distro-to-install-to-sd-card-to-use-as-usb-bootloader-for-pc

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3441/optimal-linux-distro-to-install-to-sd-card-to-use-as-usb-bootloader-for-pc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got an HTC Touch Pro (Windows Mobile OS), and it will pass the MicroSD through as a USB disk. I can boot off it, though I haven't tried Linux I don't see why it would be that much different.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Motorola droid that I use as a bootable AV disk. Mine acted just fine as a usb stick, however I have seen it not work on other phones. I know that the samsung galaxy S was having problems acting as a mass storage device on windows 7 64 bit, I needed to find a driver for it. However I have not tried booting to the samsung.